# Blazor Client (Web Assembly) AuthenticationState updates only after page reloading

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a problem with Blazor authentication. I have `AuthenticationStateProvider` implementation and everything works fine, but after login or logout I need to manually refresh page to update `AuthenticationState`.

For example I have a Profile.razor page component with `@attribute [Authorize]`. I can't open this page after login, like I'm not authorized, but after page reloading everything is fine. Same thing with logout.

I suspect that `NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync())` does nothing, but I can't understand what is wrong.

TokenAuthenticationStateProvider.cs - Implementation of `AuthenticationStateProvider`

```
public class TokenAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly TokenStorage tokenStorage;

    public TokenAuthenticationStateProvider(TokenStorage tokenStorage)
    {
        this.tokenStorage = tokenStorage;
    }

    public void StateChanged()
    {
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync()); // <- Does nothing
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var token = await tokenStorage.GetAccessToken();
        var identity = string.IsNullOrEmpty(token)
            ? new ClaimsIdentity()
            : new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(token), "jwt");
        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Claim> ParseClaimsFromJwt(string jwt)
    {
        var payload = jwt.Split('.')[1];
        var jsonBytes = ParseBase64WithoutPadding(payload);
        var keyValuePairs = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonBytes);
        return keyValuePairs.Select(kvp => new Claim(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString()));
    }

    private static byte[] ParseBase64WithoutPadding(string base64)
    {
        switch (base64.Length % 4)
        {
            case 2: base64 += "=="; break;
            case 3: base64 += "="; break;
        }
        return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    }
}
```

TokenStorage.cs - Access and Refresh tokens storage

```
public class TokenStorage
{
    private readonly ILocalStorage localStorage;

    public TokenStorage(
        ILocalStorage localStorage)
    {
        this.localStorage = localStorage;
    }

    public async Task SetTokensAsync(string accessToken, string refreshToken)
    {
        await localStorage.SetItem("accessToken", accessToken);
        await localStorage.SetItem("refreshToken", refreshToken);
    }

    public async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
        return await localStorage.GetItem<string>("accessToken");
    }

    public async Task<string> GetRefreshToken()
    {
        return await localStorage.GetItem<string>("refreshToken");
    }

    public async Task RemoveTokens()
    {
        await localStorage.RemoveItem("accessToken");
        await localStorage.RemoveItem("refreshToken");
    }
}
```

AccountService.cs - Service with login and logout methods. I call `authState.StateChanged()` to update `AuthenticationState`

```
public class AccountService
{
    private readonly TokenStorage tokenStorage;
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
    private readonly TokenAuthenticationStateProvider authState;
    private readonly string authApiUrl = "/api/authentication";

    public AccountService(
        TokenStorage tokenStorage,
        HttpClient httpClient,
        TokenAuthenticationStateProvider authState)
    {
        this.tokenStorage = tokenStorage;
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
        this.authState = authState;
    }

    public async Task Login(LoginCredentialsDto credentials)
    {
        var response = await httpClient.PostJsonAsync<AuthenticationResponseDto>($"{authApiUrl}/login", credentials);
        await tokenStorage.SetTokensAsync(response.AccessToken, response.RefreshToken);
        authState.StateChanged();
    }

    public async Task Logout()
    {
        var refreshToken = await tokenStorage.GetRefreshToken();
        await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<AuthenticationResponseDto>($"{authApiUrl}/logout/{refreshToken}");
        await tokenStorage.RemoveTokens();
        authState.StateChanged();
    }
}
```

App.razor

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" Context="routeData">
        <Found>
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <h1>Not authorized!</h1>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Profile.razor

```
@page "/profile/{UserName}"
@attribute [Authorize]

<h1>Profile</h1>

@code {
    ...
}
```

Startup.cs - Client Startup

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<LoginCredentialsDtoValidator>();
        services.AddStorage();

        services.AddScoped<TokenStorage>();
        services.AddScoped<AccountService>();

        services.AddScoped<TokenAuthenticationStateProvider>();
        services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, TokenAuthenticationStateProvider>();

        services.AddAuthorizationCore();
    }

    public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.AddComponent<App>("app");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your Startup classes, both on the client and on the server...

Comment: @enet I updated my post and added Startup.cs from my client. I can also provide Startup.cs from my server, but I use the exact server with Angular frontend and everything works fine. I receive valid access token after login, but it seems that Blazor is not receiving updated AuthenticationState.

Comment: @enet thanks, I just found my mistake and it was in client Startup.cs file.

Comment: I have the exact opposite problem :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found my mistake. The problem was in Startup.cs file on client side.

Instead of:

```
services.AddScoped<TokenAuthenticationStateProvider>();
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, TokenAuthenticationStateProvider>();
```

I need to register my services this way:

```
services.AddScoped<TokenAuthenticationStateProvider>();
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<TokenAuthenticationStateProvider>());
```

Now everything works!

Comment: Could you please explain why and how the changed code solved your issue...

Comment: @enet: Why and how: The wrong lines will add 2 implementations of TokenAuthenticationStateProvider. AccountService will use the first one because it looks for a TokenAuthenticationStateProvider. The Razor code uses the second one because it looks for an AuthenticationStateProvider. With the corrected lines only 1 implementation is created and re-used for the AuthenticationStateProvider.

Comment: @ Marcel W , thanks for your response... but wouldn't this code be sufficient:  services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, TokenAuthenticationStateProvider>();

Comment: @enet As far as I can tell not, because they need to inject TokenAuthenticationStateProvider when they do their login. Injecting AuthenticationStateProvider and casting it to the correct type would work in this exact scenario, but that breaks principles of DI somewhat. So they have to add TokenAuthenticationStateProvider seperately.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it didn't work is because you're relying on DI to do the instantiation work for you, and both calls create separate instances of the same provider.

If you want to do it right, try this:

```
var provider = new TokenAuthenticationStateProvider();
services.AddSingleton(c => provider);
services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationStateProvider>(c => provider);
```

That way, no matter how you resolve the service, you'll get the same instance. If this is a client-side app, you don't need a Scoped instance because the application is running locally inside a single browser window.

HTH!

Comment: does this apply to blazor server side as well?